# SSIS Package with Excel as source

Tags: sql-server, excel, ssis

I have an Excel sheet with some headers and logos in it. I want to create a SSIS package of that Excel but when I created the package I am not getting the required column names. How do I get the exact column names in SQl as in Excel sheet ?

This is the sheet i am working with

[image]

Comment: you have to put column name into one row, and use the `open Rowset` properties to define which part of sheet you would like to import

Answer (score 2):

As user LONG started to say in the comments, if you have an oddly laid out Excel sheet, you will need to explicitly specify the range of data within the larger sheet.

You are particularly worse off because your column names span multiple rows. There's no workaround for this, so the connection manager is going to give you column names like `F1`, `F2`, and so on.

In this screenshot, I've specified in the "OpenRowset" property of my SSIS package that my data lives on the sheet named "DATA INPUT SECTIONS" and I want the range starting from `A2` through column `AE`. I've not specified an end row so as to pull in all available rows.

[image: SSIS Specifying OPENROWSET]

Answer (score 0):

I can't see your image because it is blocked by my firm's firewall, but I think you should take a look at these links.

https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/ssis/moving-data-from-excel-to-sql-server-10-steps-to-follow/

https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/ssis/importing-excel-data-into-sql-server-via-ssis-questions-you-were-too-shy-to-ask/

https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/846480/Import-Data-from-Excel-to-SQL-Using-SSIS-Dynamic-C

https://www.sqlshack.com/using-ssis-packages-import-ms-excel-data-database/